# Details rows inside tablix SSRS Reporting service, Records with Details rows under it

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, reporting, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Now it is a  report with a **tablix**  in which the records are like 
  ***every row has some details rows under it.***  
 and the details row can have one or more records based on the main tablix rows

To elucidate the problem, plz have a look 
[image]

---

Did some search here and there, but not able to figure out how to accomplish this. 
Sub-reports inside the tablix cell, but how will it keep the track of the current row  

One thing more : Do I need to create two separate datasets for this and bind accordingly or write query as a single dataset and do some **grouping** ?

any ideas !

P.S: **SSRS** *r2 environment,* *native mode* reports for web application

Comment: Hiten004's answer is the one I'd go with. To add a subreport just right click the cell and select Insert > Subreport. Then you can right click it and select subreport properties to customize according to your needs.

Comment: @eestein yes it is solved now! but I wonder where did my image go, after questions are answered..I dont think that the images are removed ..??

Comment: You are probably using some sort of firewall/proxy that's blocking the image. Here I can see it fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create report with subreport will solve your problem

1. you can create one report with one dataset with (BIL NoB NoW Est    TotalXYZ) columns.
2. Now link that subreport with the BIL
3. Now link subreport with main report the BIL (FK)

Hope this help

Comment: Thanx, it helped out ..but still checking regarding the business

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with **one Dataset** and **one Tablix**.

The Dataset will have all the columns in the report, with multiple rows for each BIL value.

The Tablix will have **four rows** and **one group based on BIL**.

The first row will be the Tablix header row, with the main column header details.

The next two rows will be group header rows. The first row will contain the group details, *BIL*, *No Bayar*, etc. The second row will contain the detail row header details.

The last row will be the detail row which will contain the *COL1* and *COL2* detail values.

You will see something like this (you'll need to fill in the TextBox details as appropriate):

[image]

Comment: As of now @Henti's answer works for me, but if it is business wise incorrect then need to try ur one also.. +1 for the fact that my report before I made some changes was somewhat like what U've mentioned,was done by other developer.. so ur sol also mus b working one ! Thnx once again

Comment: thank u very much for the effort Ian, but I tried this before , but the problem is the single query which returns duplicate records this way,even after using DISTINCT so had to separate the query into two datasets, to avoid duplicacy, AND finally use in the way of  sub-reports